# Svg inline breaks page

Tags: html, svg, inline

I'm just trying to insert an SVG exported from Illustrator inside a div. I have it working 100% with a different SVG, I just wanted to update to this new one. I haven't minified or edited the code at all out of Illustrator.

How do I even go about troubleshooting this?

svg code: http://pasted.co/3cf2ef13

Comment: That is a ton of lines to go for. Why don't you debug it yourself? Take everything out, and progressively add stuff back it. Then you know which lines broke your SVG.

Comment: Also, check closely for missing end-quotes and missing closing tags.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions chaps. I thought that might be the only way. I've tried removing each id group individually and in stages, but no clues. I also have several more (larger) svg's to create so if this keeps happening it's not really workable. 

Would another method of implementing the svg perhaps work?

I had hoped to animate (javascript) using id tags assigned by illustrator based on layer names. As long as I could still do this maybe I could try to learn how to implement the Svg's differently?

Comment: It was the xml line at the top! doh.